# Calculations not giving the exact output in result field

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get the sum of and deduction of a calculated field in a the result form, though is working but not working correct this is my code the issue is the if i type 10 to the price field i'd get 1 in the result and if i increase with 100 the result field will be 10, if i should remove 0 from the price field the result field increment to 100 kind of confuse this is my code here

```
 const [price, setPrice] = useState(0)
 const [setamount, setCodAmount] = useState(0)
 const [result, setResult ] = useState(0)

 const num1 = parseFloat(price)
 const num2 = parseFloat(setamount)

 const handleSetPrice = (e) => {
 setPrice(parseFloat(e.target.value))
 setResult(price)
 console.log(price)
 }

 const handleSetCodAmount = (e) => {
  const codamount = e.target.value
  setCodAmount(codamount)
  const sum = num1 - num2;
  setResult(sum)
 }


 <input 
  type="number" 
  value={price}
  onChange={handleSetPrice}
 />

 <input 
  type="number" 
  value={setamount}
  onChange={handleSetCodAmount}                              
 />

 <input readOnly 
  type="text" 
  className="form-control" 
  value={result}
 />


 i tried doing this 1000 - 100 = 990 

 expecting 900
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want, but i know where the error comes from.

You are doing the operation `num1 - num2` in `handleSetCodAmount` right after using `setCodAmount`, so at this precise moment, `num2` still has the previous value (because React update the state asynchronously for performance reason).

A better usage would be to use the hook `useEffect` every time `price` or `setamount` is updated

```
useEffect(() => {
   const num1 = parseFloat(price)
   const num2 = parseFloat(setamount)
   const sum = num1 - num2;
   setResult(sum);
}, [setamount, price])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-curran-tkq7yz?file=/demo.js

You don't need num1 and num2 for this. Because, num1 and num2 variables outside the function, which are not updated dynamically with the latest values of price and setamount

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function DisableElevation() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [setamount, setCodAmount] = useState(0);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

  const handleSetPrice = (e) => {
    setPrice(parseFloat(e.target.value));
    setResult(price);
    console.log(price);
  };

  const handleSetCodAmount = (e) => {
    const codamount = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    setCodAmount(codamount);
    const sum = parseFloat(price) - codamount;
    setResult(sum);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="number" value={price} onChange={handleSetPrice} />
      <input type="number" value={setamount} onChange={handleSetCodAmount} />
      <input readOnly type="text" className="form-control" value={result} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useState` updates the state variable for next render, see the related [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats). Thus, the `setResult(price);` in `handleSetPrice` will use outdated value.

The `result` gets different value based on which `onChange` function is called. Instead of using `useState` for result, you could just normal `const` variable for it. The value of the variable is calculated on each render.

```js
const [price, setPrice] = useState(0)
const [codAmount, setCodAmount] = useState(0)

const result = price - codAmount;
```